# Update Query with LEFT JOIN , Variable and Autoincrement Using MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, auto-increment

I am stuck on a situation. Here is the table structures.

default_category

```
category_id | parent_id |   name                | symbol 
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1       |   1       |   SMT Equipment       |   SMT
    2       |   1       |   ATE & INSPECTION    |   ATE
    3       |   1       |   Feeders             |   FED
    4       |   1       |   Rework Station      |   RWS
    5       |   1       |   X-Ray Machines      |   XRM
```

default_products

```
id  | subcategory_id | product_name | product_code
---------------------------------------------------
1   |   1           |   A           |   null
2   |   1           |   B           |   null
3   |   2           |   C           |   null
4   |   2           |   D           |   null
5   |   1           |   E           |   null
6   |   3           |   F           |   null
7   |   4           |   G           |   null
8   |   1           |   H           |   null
9   |   2           |   I           |   null
```

default_products_code

```
id  | category_id | code    
-------------------------
1   |       1     | 1   
2   |       2     | 1       
3   |       3     | 1   
4   |       4     | 1       
5   |       5     | 1
```

Now here is the detail

Whenever a category is created i make an entry in default_products_code 
and provide code = 1 as default value. Now when ever a product is inserted
i get the code from default_products_code and symbol from default_category
and make a code like this for example for product A the code is  SMT0001
and than i update the code in default_products_code to 2 because 1 has been 
assigned in the product_code. This is what my current system is. But now the problem 
comes that there are hundrad of products in my database and i have to update the 
newly added column with the above criteria i explained.

This is the query i have tried with auto increment

```
SET @var := 1;
UPDATE default_products AS dp
LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT 
                dc.category_id,
                CONCAT(symbol, LPAD(@var,5,'0')) AS `code`,
                @var := @var+1
            FROM default_products AS dp
            LEFT JOIN default_category AS dc ON dc.category_id = dp.subcategory_id
            WHERE subcategory_id = 1
        ) AS l ON l.category_id = dp.subcategory_id 
SET part_code = l.code
WHERE subcategory_id = 1;
```

It produces this result

```
id  | subcategory_id | product_name | product_code
---------------------------------------------------
1   |   1           |   A           |   SMT00001
2   |   1           |   B           |   SMT00001
5   |   1           |   E           |   SMT00001
8   |   1           |   H           |   SMT00001
```

While i need this

```
id  | subcategory_id | product_name | product_code
---------------------------------------------------
1   |   1           |   A           |   SMT00001
2   |   1           |   B           |   SMT00002
5   |   1           |   E           |   SMT00003
8   |   1           |   H           |   SMT00004
```

Another thing i need to update all products within the table.
How can i do this in a single query.I know i need to remove 
WHERE subcategory_id = 1 in this case but i am unable to proceed.

Comment: you should back to my query solution in your previous question :)

Comment: that helps in SELECt but not in update i have already tried

Comment: are you looking for string modification in your queries, to set the product_code according to your id? Something like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some modifications i have found how to do it.

```
SET @var := 0;
UPDATE default_products AS dp
LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
        dc.category_id,
        dc.symbol
        FROM default_products AS dp
        LEFT JOIN default_category AS dc ON dc.category_id = dp.subcategory_id
        WHERE subcategory_id = 16
        group by dp.id            
    ) AS l ON l.category_id = dp.subcategory_id 
SET part_code = CONCAT(l.symbol, LPAD(@var := @var+1,5,'0'))
WHERE subcategory_id = 16;
```

I have taken out code creation and it is working exactly as i need. I still want to update it with 
the where condition removed so i can update all products.

Comment: @BillKarwin can you please help me with this

Comment: @JW can you help me with this. I want to update all records for which i know i will have to reset variable to 0 each time when a new group is selected

Answer (score 2):

your problem is with `LPAD`

[LPAD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php) is defined like that

```
   LPAD(str, len, padstr)
```

in your query u should use like that

```
 LPAD(id, 5, 0)
```

in your query `LPAD(@var,5,'0')` it will return always 00001 as `@var` is 1

Comment: yes but why in my query @var := @var+1 does not have eny effect?

Comment: u dont need this `@var := @var+1` just remove it

Comment: u dont need that variable `$var` at all it will follows the `id`

Comment: `LPAD(id, 5, 0)` look that , it will follow the id automatically so u dont need to put variable

Comment: i have provided id as sample data. products may be in any order some ids missing in the middle what will i do than? for example 1 ,2 3, 10 , 16, 100. In this case i can't use id.

Comment: then make variable for the 5 to adjust the length. if length of id is 2 then this new_variable will not be 5 it will be 4 just example

Comment: create vraiable for the length 5

Comment: other option is to make as you done and make a loop like that `SET @var = 1;
  insert_loop: LOOP`  ...........`END LOOP subcat_loop;`

Comment: look here how it explained the loop for your variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107803/how-to-use-nested-loops-and-varaibles-in-mysql-statement

Comment: but i had to do it manually but i am still interested to see how i can do it with only a single query

Comment: where is or from where it comes this `part_code` ? have you column of it?