# create Student ID number with year and auto incremented value

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i created a student id number compose of text and auto incremented value like: KP0001 - KP9999 it will reset to KP0001 again, It will result to duplicate ID number. I changed it to this: 2013-00001 but it's not working i dont know why.

this is what i tried:

```
text  id
KP    1
KP    2
KP    3

SELECT * ,concat(text,LPAD(id,4,'0')) as stud_id FROM students
```

i want to change the text into year which will update yearly.
Thanks, Mills

Comment: post some schema , sample data , desired out put and what you have tried.

Comment: done editing the previous post

Comment: Well take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033079/update-query-with-left-join-variable-and-autoincrement-using-mysql). You might want something similar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
  *,
  concat(YEAR(NOW()),'-',LPAD(id,5,'0')) as stud_id
FROM students
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

OUTPUT

```
id  text    stud_id
--------------------
1   KP      2013-00001
2   KP      2013-00002
3   KP      2013-00003
```

You can use this update query

```
UPDATE students AS s
LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT 
        *
        FROM students
    ) AS l ON l.id = s.id
SET s.text = concat(YEAR(NOW()),'-',LPAD(l.id,5,'0'))
```

Comment: how about when i insert the current year?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. Please tell me clearly. Also see NOW() is selecting current datetime and YEAR() is extracting year from it

Comment: i mean i want to insert the current year in the database